# When is it ever appropriate to call fileExistsAtPath?

Tags: cocoa

The documentation for fileExistsAtPath reads:

> Attempting to predicate behavior based on the current state of the
>   file system or a particular file on the file system is not
>   recommended. Doing so can cause odd behavior or race conditions. It’s
>   far better to attempt an operation (such as loading a file or creating
>   a directory), check for errors, and handle those errors gracefully
>   than it is to try to figure out ahead of time whether the operation
>   will succeed. For more information on file-system race conditions, see
>   Race Conditions and Secure File Operations in Secure Coding Guide.

But this seems ridiculous to me. fileExistsAtPath returns a BOOL, and clearly would normally be used to "predicate behavior" and choose between code paths, e.g. using a conditional. So the way this documentation is worded, seems to imply that fileExistsAtPath should *never* be used - but that makes no sense.

What is a practical use of fileExistsAtPath that does not attempt to predicate behavior? Do any exist?

And if there is none, and the documentation is just poorly worded, what are practical uses of fileExistsAtPath that predicate behavior and are actually safe given the warning?

Answer (score 2):

Well "not recommended" is not the same as "should *never* be used".

The fact is, `-fileExistsAtPath:` and APIs like it have been commonplace for a long time. Over that time, programmers have gained painful experience that they are often misused and can lead to security problems. So, their documentation has been amended to include such warnings that you generally shouldn't use them.

In particular, just because `-fileExistsAtPath:` returned true doesn't mean the file will still exist when you go to access it. And just because it returned false doesn't mean it won't exist if you try to create something in its place (and your attempt may fail or you may instead open a file rather than creating one).

You need to carefully handle all cases regardless of what `-fileExistsAtPath:` may have told you, so it's usually best to just not call it. It's wasted code.

That said, there are some cases where it is appropriate to use. For example, if your UI has a control to delete a file that your app "owns", you may disable that control if the file doesn't exist. But you would want to recheck on each pass through your app's event/update loop. Also, if it's enabled because the file did exist recently, then your app must not fail or do something bad if it doesn't exist when it actually tries to delete it.